# N1QL query count for each document of specific type

Tags: sql, couchbase, sql++

I am new to couchbase and to non-relational DB.

I have a bucket with players and teams(2 types of documents).
each player has type, playedFor(an array with all the teams he played) and a name for example:

```
{
    "type":"player"
    "name":"player1"
    "playedFor": [
          "England/Manchester/United"
          "England/Manchester/City"
          ]
}
```

each team has type, name and category for example:

```
{
    "type": "team"
    "name": "England/Manchester/City"
    "category": "FC"
}
```

I want to know how many players played for each team of category FC.
I made this query to calc for specific team:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS total 
FROM bucket AS a 
WHERE a.type='player' 
AND (any r in a.playedFor satisfies r in ["England/Manchester/United"] end)
```

but how can i make this query for all teams?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wrinkle in the way you've modeled this data is that player can play for 1 or more teams (hence the array).

One way to approach this is to use Couchbase's [UNNEST clause](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/unnest.html) to "flatten" these arrays (it's basically joining the document to each of the items in the array).

At that point, it becomes as easy as a standard `GROUP BY`. Here's an example:

```
SELECT team, count(1) AS totalPlayers
FROM `bucket` AS a 
UNNEST a.playedFor team
WHERE a.type='player'
GROUP BY team
```

This query would generate output like:

```
[
  {
    "team": "Pittsburgh/Pirates",
    "totalPlayers": 8
  },
  {
    "team": "England/Manchester/United",
    "totalPlayers": 10
  },
  {
    "team": "England/Manchester/City",
    "totalPlayers": 15
  },
  {
    "team": "Cincinnati/Reds",
    "totalPlayers": 21
  }
]
```

(Sorry, I used MLB teams to augment your sample, since I don't know much about soccer teams).

Notice that the separate team documents don't figure into this query, but you could also `JOIN` to them if you need information from them for your quer(ies).

Comment: Thanks a lot it works!!!
Still need to filter by category. 
Will do it and post the full answer.
:)